# How to backup Angry Birds saves/data?

Tags: backup, angry-birds

I need to reinstall my Android ROM but before I would like to backup my Angry Birds savegame/data/scores.

Do you have any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Angry Birds' data would be stored inside the phones memory under the folder **Data**. Access to that folder is not permitted to you or any app for security reasons.

Without having **root** access there is no way to access that folder or backup your app. However once you've obtained root access you could either extract the data yourself or use an application like

[Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup):

[image: Titanium Backup QR code]

Comment: I highly recommend Titanium Backup for root users.  Especially if you like to flash new mods a lot.

Comment: I used Titanium Backup with root permission, it worked very well.

Comment: not even when from a PC?

Comment: @Louis Rhys: You can access it through ADB, but IIRC it won't show up in USB Mass Storage mode.

Answer (score 37):

Yes you can back up your Angry Birds data, **without rooting your phone**! It takes a few steps, and it's a manual process, but pretty easy nonetheless. This works with my Samsung Android 2 phone.

1. Install the Android SDK onto your computer from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. You will be using the ADB program, part of the SDK's Platform-Tools.
2. Connect your Android device to your computer **in debugging mode**. On my Galaxy S Android 2 phone, I had to go to Settings / Applications / Development and turn on USB Debugging before connecting the cable.
3. On your computer, start a Command Prompt and run these commands:

```
    cd "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools"
    adb pull /data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds/files/highscores.lua C:\MyBackup\ab_highscores.lua
    adb pull /data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds/files/settings.lua C:\MyBackup\ab_settings.lua
```

Of course, supply your own directory names depending on where you installed the Android SDK, and where you want the files saved.

To restore the files later:

1. Reinstall Angry Birds and complete at least one level. (This ensures the device has the appropriate directories.)
2. Connect your device in debugging mode and start a Command Prompt, as done above. Run these commands:

```
    cd "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools"
    adb push C:\MyBackup\ab_highscores.lua /data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds/files/highscores.lua
    adb push C:\MyBackup\ab_settings.lua /data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds/files/settings.lua
```

Q: Is it safe?
A: Yes! The Android SDK is provided by Google, the developers of Android, for use by software developers that write applications for Android devices. ADB, its Android Debugging Bridge is the official way that Google wants developers to interact with their Android devices. As long as you are careful with what files you push/pull, it's fine.

Q: How about Angry Birds Seasons?
A: Same as above, but type "angrybirdsseasons" instead of "angrybirds" (and of course change the name of the local backup file!).

Comment: It works! I've tested it with linux, and works fine at least to pull those files from the device. When I reinstall (or upgrade) my android, I will know if it works too pushing them back.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I did it with angrybirds rio (com.rovio.angrybirdsrio) and it worked flawlessly. You have to type of the path exactly though, and you can't navigate the filesystem on the android device with adb shell. You'll get lots of permission denied errors if you're not root. Oh, and I did it with a galaxy tab 10.1.

Comment: Works perfectly. I exported them from a Xperia X10 mini to a Nexus S. This answer should be the selected answer to the question, indeed.

Answer (score 7):

There is a program called "Angry Birds Backup" on the market that allows you to back your progress up without having root access. I've not tried it myself, but I've heard good things. You can read more about it on their web site at http://www.angrybackup.com/

Answer (score 4):

I used a program by Antbee called Angry Birds Backup. It worked great, and it was free. For Seasons and Rio, I used Angry Birds Seasons Backup and Angry Birds Rio Backup by Whitney Powell. All three worked flawlessly.
It saved me from having to root my phone and/or replay all those levels.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this since I am rooted, but I assume ADB will allow you to access the data via shell. At worst you can copy over the data into a directory on the sd card. Restoring it would be problematic.

ADB = Android Debugging tool as part of the android SDK.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Fortunately unrevoked has a tool to root your phone as an application exploit so that you don't get the 100% root (can do nandroid and replace kernels) but you can run titanium backup.

www.unrevoked.com (unrevoked forever is the 1-click root). Check their list for supported devices.

As long as your phone is not bricked, this should not void your warranty as long as you just run titanium and remove unrevoked + titanium when returning the phone.

Comment: ADB won't give you access to the **data** directory unless you're rooted. But once you've rooted it, then you should be able to.

Comment: @mlevit: Dang! Yet another reason to root.