# Remote path to Angry Birds Space savegames

Tags: angry-birds

I'm following [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/8793/13618) on how to backup Angry Birds settings and hi-scores using Android Debugging Bridge. The command:

```
adb pull /data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds/files/highscores.lua C:\ab_highscores.lua
```

works perfectly for Angry Birds original, Rio and Seasons. The paths I need to change are:

- `angrybirds` for original Angry Birds
- `angrybirdsrio` for Angry Birds Rio
- `angrybirdsseasons` for Angry Birds Seasons

Now, what is the path for Space? The most obvious one, `angrybirdsspace` is giving me error "Remote object not found". 
Alternatively, how can I list content of `/data/data` folder? I think it's not possible with ADB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`adb shell ls -l /data/data` command will get you the file and directory listing you are looking for.

Specifically for Angry Birds Space, try `adb pull com.rovio.angrybirdsspace.ads/files/highscores.lua C:\abs_highscores.lua`