# Back up not only games, but also game progress before flashing ROMS

Tags: backup, data-transfer

I have a Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100) And I'm about to flash a custom rom on it. I've done it a bunch of times but what really irritates me is that I lose all progress made on the games that I have on my phone!

I backup the actual games and other applications using Astro file manager, but when I star my phone up after flashing a rom and re-install the game, I have lost all progress.

How does one backup a game, **with game progress intact**?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to backup an Android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device) and [Backup Angry Birds](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/how-to-backup-angry-birds-saves-data) and see also [how to use adb backup](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/how-to-backup-angry-birds-saves-data)

Comment: I believe it's slightly different. He's asking how to backup app data specifically, which could be the case with angry birds, if it didn't have dedicated backup apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another fool-proof method (no need to worry about having a specific backup app) is to grab the game's data directly.

The data for all user-installed apps can be found in `/data/data/*package name*`. This will be all settings, saves, and anything else.  Just browse into there and copy the relevant directories to somewhere safe and put them back when you're done flashing and have reinstalled the app and run it at least once.

Yet another way, which will work without root, is you do the same as above, but using adb.  Turn on USB debugging, connect up to your computer, and run `adb pull /data/data/*package name* C:\where\you\want\the\files`.

Then once you're done with your ROM flashing and have reinstalled the apps, do `adb push C:\where\you\put\the\files /data/data/*package name*`, or if you now have root with your custom ROM, just copy the directories you pulled to the SD card and put them back in `/data/data` on the device.

Comment: The syntax for adb push or pull is the wrong way around

Comment: Got push right, but pull was backwards, fixed now.  Need more coffee.

Answer (score 6):

The best are backup methods that backup and restore **app data**. [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) is excellent for this, and easy to do, especially with the [pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmtlcmFtaWRhcy5UaXRhbml1bUJhY2t1cFBybyJd). It allows you to backup the apps, *including the relevant app data, which holds the game progress*. The pro version lets you restore them seamlessly, while the free version requires manual re-install, like Astro. You can also sync these backups to online storage spaces like dropbox or Google Drive.

If you have multiple devices (I have a tablet and phone that I like to sync progress on, for example), [DataSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quintstoffers.DataSync.beta&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLnF1aW50c3RvZmZlcnMuRGF0YVN5bmMuYmV0YSJd) is by far the best option. It can sync to dropbox or strictly device-to-device, but can sync all the app data *with game progress* to another device for subsequent use, or resyncing back to the original device later.

Let us know what you choose!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! Does your phone need to be rooted to use titanium backup though?

Comment: Yes, TB's most useful features require root.  However, seeing how you are about to flash a custom ROM on your phone, it's a pretty safe bet you've already rooted it.

Comment: It does require root, unfortunately the only way to back up app data from the internal system is to have root access. The answer below describes the manual method, but this will also require a root access file browser. And as @Chahk pointed out, new ROMs usually mean root, I was assuming :)

Answer (score 3):

Give a try to [Go Backup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.go.backup.ex&hl=en) which is completely free. It need root access and backup your **apps+data**, and when you will restore your backup it will not ask you **Install app** every time.

> Backup contacts,messages,GO launcher settings, system setting and apps
>   Backup apps data（needs ROOT）
>   Hide annoying app installation interface when restore apps（needs ROOT)
>   Cloud Backup supported, sync to Dropbox.