# How to back up applications in Android?

Tags: backup, htc-one-x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device)

If I have installed N number of applications including big games, and I would like to back up them, so I could restore the games as soon as I factory reset my mobile, how can it be done ?

Any free apps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Titanium Backup](http://www.matrixrewriter.com/android/), but your phone needs to have root. It has a FREE and a PAID version.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference in between FREE and PAID ?

Comment: I installed Titanium FREE but I could not find it on my app list, seems it needs rooting or bootloader installed ?

Is it rooting requires bootloader installed on device ? and is it updating OS requires rooting ?

Comment: @KusH Yes, you need root to use Titanium Backup.

Comment: Does rooting require boot loader ?

Comment: @KusH You need to unlock the bootloader so you can have root. Check the the guides / instructions online on how to root your phone (e.g. using Odin to root your phone).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your Android version, and whether you are rooted or not, there are multiple possibilities. On all rooted devices, you can use [Titanium Backup ★ root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) (pro version recommended -- there's nothing like it). For non-rooted devices, there's no app that can really backup everything (which is an *intended* permission issue for security reasons: no app can directly access another app's data). But provided you're running at least ICS (Android 4.0.*) or higher, take a look at the question [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/16575/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) or [File Expert](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xcxin.filexpert) to backup your apk's, it will only  backup your apps not the data. And they will do it with free versions.

From this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/34715/12332)

To backup your app data you should have to rooted to use any application that can backup the data. But if you have not rooted then you can try the following command which will work without root, but using adb. Turn on USB debugging, connect up to your computer, and run

> adb pull /data/data/*package name* C:\where\you\want\the\files.

Answer (score 0):

There is also AppMonster. It is available as both a [free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager) and a [paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.think_android.appmanagerpro) app (€2.96) on the Play Store. [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) is nice too (it gives more significant names to the backed up APKs) but AppMonster is better. I use both of them and AppMonster can back up apps that ES File Explorer does even not find ([Seesmic Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seesmic.pro) for example). I almost asked a question about "un-backup-able" apps on the site because of that.