# How can transfer my game progress from HTC Legend to Samung Galaxy S3?

Tags: data-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup Angry Birds saves/data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/how-to-backup-angry-birds-saves-data)
>   [New phone: How to transfer game progress?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21112/new-phone-how-to-transfer-game-progress)

I don't really want to root either phone. But if I absolutely had to, I could root the HTC Legend, but definitely not the Samsung Galaxy S3.

Comment: Why can't you root the Samsung Galaxy S3? Is there any specific reason why?

Comment: It's a brand new phone that is quite expensive and I don't want to be stuck if it develops any problems or bricks itself.

Comment: If it were safe, would you do it? There's a noob-friendly guide for rooting the S3 here (from a reputable source too): http://www.xda-developers.com/android/how-to-root-the-samsung-galaxy-s-iii-xda-developer-tv/

Comment: No, I am definately not going to root the S3. It can't really be flagged as a duplicate can it since they are different phones and most likely different android versions.

Comment: There must be a way to access the /data/data folder on the HTC Legend without rooting it since those apps that modify Angry Birds saves can access it. Once I aquire the data could I just use the restor feature in the S3 application settings.

Comment: You need to be rooted to access that /data/data folder - plain and simple :)

Comment: @t0mm13b if I did root my HTC and copied the data out of that directory, would it be possible to add them to the S3 without rooting it.

Comment: You need both handsets to be rooted for that to pull off! Try using Google Backup to the cloud on HTC Legend (**what android version is on that?**) and restore on the SGS3.

Comment: The HTC is on Android 2.2

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/how-to-backup-angry-birds-saves-data) question about Angry Birds...

Comment: Since this question is about angry birds data save/restore, it should be flagged duplicate as per the linky in my previous comment...

Comment: Ive read through that link, but I'm having trouble getting it to locate the sdk files. I've tried numerous times typing it but it simply isn't there.

Comment: If it's just about AngryBirds: Why not use [AngryBirds Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fankewong.angrybirdsbackup2sd) (there are at least two more backup apps for those birds)?

Comment: angry birsd is one app I need to transfer but the one I'mmost concerned bout is Jetpack Joyride.

Answer (score 3):

As long as none of the devices runs JellyBean (Android 4.1 and up), and it's just about those Angry Birds (as the comments suggest), take a look at [AngryBirds Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fankewong.angrybirdsbackup2sd):

[image: AngryBirds backup]

As the screenshot shows, the app supports a variety of the AngryBirds games (I don't know if it's complete, as I'm no "gamer", but it looks pretty much). So use this app to backup your AngryBirds data from the old phone to SD, copy the data to the SD card of the new phone, and use the very same app to restore them there.