# How to backup locally stored game data?

Tags: backup, restore, data-transfer

I'm looking to upgrade from a Nexus 7 to a 10" tablet. I know that Google stores my purchase information so that I won't have to pay for any already purchased games again.

But I was wondering if it's possible to transfer my locally stored game data to the new device so that I can continue without loss of progress. If so, how is it done?

Comment: Please see: [How can transfer my game progress from HTC Legend to Samung Galaxy S3?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38179/16575) / [New phone: How to transfer game progress?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21112/16575) / [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575)

Comment: See also: [Back up not only games, but also game progress before flashing ROMS](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34687)